# PHP access a database in MS SQL server 2008 r2

Tags: php, sql-server

Dears,

I have a php application and I cannot access the SQL server database even though I installed the drivers and modify the php.ini file.

when I write the following code it doesn't provide me with an output

```
$servername = "localhost";
$info = array('Databse'=>'Test');

$con = sqlsrv_connect($servername);   

if($con)
{
    echo "Success";
}
else
{
    echo "Failure";
}
```

anything below the sqlsrv_connect() is ignored.

Please help me I've been stuck in this for the past 3 weeks :(

Comment: Where is `$info` used?

Comment: 1. Where is the info?
2. Have you checked all the permissions on MSSQL? You need to have created the user there and given them permission to login from outside the SQL Studio.

Comment: Turn on error reporting and check for errors.

Comment: Add to the beginning of the script: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Answer (score 0):

You could print out the connection error with using `sqlsrv_errors()`

```
$con=sqlsrv_connect($servername);   
if($con)
{
    echo "Success";
}
else
{
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));    
    echo "Faluire";
}
```

For further info check manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Comment: Still Not showing anything, the thing is that every thing after the sqlsrv_connect() is ignored , even a simple echo message.

Comment: Do you provide connection info? $serverName = "serverName"; $uid = "my_username_here"; $pwd = "my_secret_password"; $dbname = "MyDatabaseName"; $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"$dbName", "UID"=>"$uid", "PWD"=>"$pwd"); $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);